# Image field in edit mode still asking for image as a 'required' field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple form with few fields.

when I am trying to edit the form details its rendering perfectly but pan and aadhar fields are mandatory and asking again to upload the image in edit mode as well.

If I do not want to update the documents, it should post the data with prevoius reference.

But unluckly its asking me to upload image again.

So how can I override the required TRue to required False with edit mode form post ?

Could you guys please suggest me what is the problem here?

Model.py

```py
    class Student(BaseModel):
        mobile = PhoneNumberField()
        aadhar = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True, null=True)
        license = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True, null=True)
        pan = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/%Y/%m/%d',blank=True, null=True)
```

form.py

```py
    class AddDetails(forms.Form):

        aadhar = forms.ImageField(label='Upload Aadhar',required=True) 
        license = forms.ImageField(label='Upload License',required=True)
```

views.py

```py
    @login_required
    def add_edit(request, city_id=None, id=None):

        city=City.objects.get(pk=city_id)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = AddDetails(request.POST,request.FILES, request=request)
            if form.is_valid():


                aadhar = request.file['aadhar']
                license = request.file['license']


                if Student.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
                    #updates to db

                    stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)

                    stu.aadhar = aadhar
                    stu.license = license

                    stu.save()

                    messages.success(request, 'Edits Successful...')
                    return redirect("/student/1")
                else:
                    s = Student( aadhar = aadhar,license=license)
                    s.save()


                    messages.success(request, 'Details added Successfully...')
                    return redirect('/student/1')

        else:
            if Student.objects.filter(id=id).exists():
                stu = Student.objects.get(pk=id)
                form = AddDetails(initial={ 'aadhar': stu.aadhar,'license': stu.license,
                })


        context = {

            'form': form,
            'id': id,
            'city': city,

        }
        return render(request, 'dets/add_stud.html', context=context)
```

Comment: Does any solution please?